# Facing error in tensorflow2.0 while building tf_estimator

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

```
import custom_model as CM
import input_pipeline as IP
import tensorflow as tf

def custom_estimator(features, labels, mode):

  logits = CM.model_net(features=features, n_classes=5)
  prediction = tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(logits)
  preds_dict = {'class': tf.argmax(input=prediction, axis=1),
                'probabilities': prediction,
                'logits': logits}
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, 
                                      predictions=preds_dict)
  # Compute loss
  labels = tf.reshape(labels, (BATCH_SIZE, 5))
  loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true=labels,
                                                  y_pred=prediction)
  # Compute evaluation metrics
  accuracy = custom_accuracy(labels, prediction)
  metrics = {'accuracy': accuracy}
  tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, 
                                      eval_metric_ops=metrics)

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
  train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, 
                                    train_op=train_op)

# Build tf_estimator
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=custom_estimator,
                                    model_dir=model_dir)

# Train the estimator
TRAIN_FILES, TRAIN_LABELS = IP.map_file_to_label(data_dir=data_dir)
TRAIN = classifier.train(input_fn=lambda:
  IP.imgs_input_fn(TRAIN_FILES, labels=TRAIN_LABELS,
                   perform_shuffle=True, repeat_count=EPOCHS,
                   batch_size=BATCH_SIZE),
                   steps=int(len(TRAIN_LABELS)/BATCH_SIZE))
```

This is the error I am facing with TensorFlow-2.0. Error image & code for the same attached here. Please help.
If I enter var_list=None then the error is "ValueError: Passed in object of type , not tf.Tensor"

[image]

Comment: Temporary answer is replace the below 2 lines: <br/>
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam() <br/>
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss) <br/>
    with: <br/>
       optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer() <br/>
       train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, tf.compat.v1.train.get_or_create_global_step())

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think this Estimator code example is TensorFlow 2.0 compliant. In any case, if peradventure you're using the 1.x versions, replace:

```
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

with this:

```
train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=average_loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
```

If indeed, you're using TensorFlow 2.0, then replace with:

```
train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=average_loss, global_step=tf.compat.v1.train.get_global_step())
```

Comment: I am using TF2.0 version.
suggestion 1, gives: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'get_global_step' 
suggestion 2, gives: TypeError: minimize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'global_step'

Comment: Custom Estimators are still somewhat flaky with TF 2.0. This code will work better with TF 1.x. I suggest you create a different virtual environment and install TensorFlow 1.15 and run this code block using my code updates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. TF2.0 is not working that well as of now, so I will go back to TF1.x version.